# XSLT 1.0 When Test expression equivalent to IN operator

Tags: xml, xslt, expression, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to do something in XSLT 1.0 like below where instead of hardcoding multiple OR operators, i'd like to use a variable that has comma-seperated-values with something that equates to an IN operator.

```
<xsl:variable name="CSV">userdefinedONe, userDefined two</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template....
  <xsl:choose...
   <xsl:when test="Name IN $CSV OR Name='hardcoded'>....
       DO SOMETHING
   ....
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Would you accept an answer that doesn't use any form of IN but does give you just one when tag? I usually do this kind of thing by creating a regular expression in the variable (so, rather than comma-delimited, bar-delimited).

Comment: @Christina - probably not. although your solution seems interesting. can you post a sample if you don't mind.

Comment: Actually, I didn't give due consideration to the 1.0 requirement. My solution in that case would be much like the one you accepted, using contains and the delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to replicate the IN behavior in XSLT 1.0 is to concatenate the delimiter for your `$CSV` as a prefix and suffix to both the `$CSV` and the `Name` values and test whether that concatenated `Name` value is contained within the concatenated `$CSV` using the `contains()` function:

```
<xsl:variable name="CSV">userdefinedONe, userDefined two</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="', '"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(concat($delimiter,$CSV,$delimiter), 
                             concat($delimiter, Name, $delimiter)) 
                    or Name='hardcoded' ">
        DO SOMETHING
        ....
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: this worked too, but @MichaelKay looks cleaner to me. Although, you did get it to work using the original requirement of using CSV, thx!!!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's appropriate to set up an XML document containing the values you are testing for:

```
<days>
  <day>Monday</day>
  <day>Tuesday</day>
  <day>Wednesday</day>
</days>
```

and then use

```
<xsl:when test="$day = document('days.xml')/days/day">
```

which returns true if $day equals any of the `<day>` values. If there are lots of values you can also make this more efficient by indexing use xsl:key:

```
<xsl:key name="d" match="day" use="."/>

<xsl:when test="key('d', $day)">
```

but you have to be careful because in XSLT 1.0 the key() function can only be used to search within the document containing the context node.

Comment: is there a way to do without the external document? can i define the xml (days.xml) in the xslt itself?

Comment: got it to work by declaring a variable and putting the XML between the tags. thx!!!

Comment: I didn't suggest using a variable because XSLT 1.0 doesn't allow you to probe into the content of a result tree fragment without using the exslt:node-set() extension. Apart from that, it's fine.

Comment: hmm i did't realize my solution was using an extension. I'm using microsoft's template in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

There is no elegant way to accomplish this with XSLT 1.0 without a little help.

You could use [exslt](http://www.exslt.org), something like this (untested example, just to illustrate the idea):

```
<xsl:variable name="name" select="Name"/>
...
   <xsl:when test="str:tokenise(concat('hardcoded', ', ', $CSV))/token[text() = $name]">...
```

Take a look at the documentation of [str:tokenise](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html)

You can achieve this also without any extensions, but it will be a lot of named templates juggling and certainly not readable. The drawback is of course that you would have to add the dependency to exslt.

Comment: sorry i don't have the option to use external libs, but thanks for the link.